# php drop down menu to execute script with argument

Tags: bash, php

I have shell script which I run like this

```
/var/www/test.sh 2015
```

or

```
/var/www/test.sh 2014
```

When this script runs, it actually takes data from freeradius and generates gnuplot base graph for the specific year in the www folder like

```
/var/www/output.jpg
```

Now I want to make a php drop down menu with years like 2015, 2014 and so on, and when user select any year, it should run the script with the specific choice year. ***But how can I pass year to the shell script.***

so far I have tried this but its not working.

```
root@rm:/var/www# cat test5.php

<html>
<head><title>some title</title></head>
<body>
  <form method="post" action="">
    <input type="text" name="something" value="<?= isset($_POST['something']) ? htmlspecialchars($_POST['something']) : '' ?>" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" />
  </form>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
echo ($_POST['something']);
// Now the script should be executed with the selected year 
      $message=shell_exec("/var/www/test.sh $something");
// and after executing the script, this page should also open the output.jpg in the browser

}
?>
</body>
<html>
root@rm:/var/www#
```

Comment: Take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9612273/3776858

Comment: I think you shoud add double quotation mark on argument on your bash since htmlspecialchar doesn't include pipe (|). it could lead to security issues. "./test.sh \"$args\""

Answer (score 0):

Drop down menu in html is a select.

```
<form method="post" action="">
    <select name="something">
        <option value="2014">year 2014</option>
        <option value="2015">year 2015</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" />
</form>
```

Then after submit

```
$something = $_POST["something"];
shell_exec("/var/www/test.sh $something");
```

Comment: This is dangerous.

Answer (score 0):

Allowing PHP to execute comands is dangerous. There are lots of things which may prevent you from achieving your goal - SELinux, Apparmor, PHP running chroot, PHP running in safe mode, disabled functions in PHP....

To ensure that the code *only* does what you intend, you need to [validate the input](http://symcbean.blogspot.com/2017/07/validate-input-escape-output.html)

```
// Since value appears to be a numeric year, lets insist that its a number
$arg=(integer)$_POST['something']; 
// in an appropriate range
if ((1970<$arg) && (3000>$arg)) {
    // this part is redundant given the checks above but included for completeness
    $arg=escapeshellarg($arg);
    $message=shell_exec("/var/www/test.sh $something");
}
```

Your code should work (even though its very insecure). The reason it did not work should be in your log files.